# Why B Tree root can have minimum degree 2?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Recently i came across a property of B tree that its root can have minimum degree 2 why it is so and is there any way to prove this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

### 1. Is the minimum of 2 guaranteed?

Yes.

Let's say the B-tree is configured to have a maximum degree of *n*, meaning that non-leaf nodes can have at the most *n-1* values.

When you start adding values to an empty B-tree, the first time that the root node gets children is when a value is added that does not fit any more in the root node. So then the root node splits into two nodes, and a new root node is created on top of them, i.e. as parent of those two nodes. So, the rule is maintained here: the root has 2 children.

When more values are added, the root may get more children, and the above may happen again: the root becomes fully occupied and needs to split... etc.

When deleting values from a B-tree, child nodes may sometimes need to merge, which may reduce the number of children that the root has. The rule is that when the root's number of children becomes 1 (and thus the root holds *no* value any more), that root node should be removed, and that child should become the new root. Since that child maintained the rule to have at least *n/2* children itself (or be a leaf), we can conclude the root will always have at least two children, or be a leaf.

### 2. Could the minimum be set higher?

No. The minimum degree cannot be more than 2.

Consider for instance the case where we would want it to be 3 (and not 2). If now we start from an empty tree and add values, and we come to the situation where the root is full, we would need to split that root into *three*. But then those 3 new nodes would have fewer than *n/2* values each, which is a violation of that other rule of B-Trees: non-root nodes should be occupied for at least 50% of their capacity...

So, ... that is why the rule for the root's degree is as it is.